# flutter test finds two `SnackBar`s with the same key, when there is only one built

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am widget-testing the app in flutter, there is 3 conditions under the block listener on the gui side of the app.

two of the three conditions determine the building of the two different `SnackBar`s, those two `SnackBar`s has different `Key`s (`error-snackbar` and `success-snackbar`), when test is run it says:

```
2 of the widget with the same key<'error-snackbar'> was found.
```

because of this I need to expect two widget with `findsNWidget(2)`

---

this is the code of the test:

```
testWidgets("Expects email to be invalid and shows error SnackBar",
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.runAsync(() async {
        //build the tree of widgets
        final widget = _buildTestableStateWidget();
        await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();

        accountBloc.emit(AccountState(
          event: event,
          error: ErrorModel(key: 'ERROR_GENERAL'),
          loading: true,
        ));
        await tester.pumpAndSettle();
        expect(find.byKey(Key("error-snackbar")), findsNWidgets(2));
      });
    });
```

### Any Idea why this is happening ?

---

just comment if you need more code and I will provide it.

Comment: same is happeninng to me i got no idea

Answer (score 0):

"Keys must be unique amongst the Elements with the same parent."
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html

Since you are trying to find 2 widgets with the same key, do they share a common parent? Then it's not allowed. You should try to build the finder in another way, Keys are made to find a specific widget.